# Three.js Change Model Source onclick

Tags: javascript, three.js

im have been playing with the examples but since my knowledge is very limited because im a bit dumb, i cant figure out how to change the Model Source of the OBJLoader on click to load a different a model.

I have created a variable "var: name" and have place it as the en source in "   loader.load( 'models/obj/goku/' + name, function"

I want to be able to create anchors where the name of the object is the Text of the anchor, but i am unable to change the source 1st.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - OBJLoader test
        </div>
<a onclick="changename('GameBoy');">click</a>
        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

            import { OBJLoader } from './jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

    import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
var controls;
            var object;

var name ="Engine.obj";


             init();
            animate();

function changename(newname){

name = newname;

}


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 250;

                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
                scene.add( ambientLight );

                var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
                camera.add( pointLight );
                scene.add( camera );



                // manager

                function loadModel() {

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                        if ( child.isMesh ) child.material.map = texture;

                    } );

                    object.position.y = -20;
                    scene.add( object );

                }

                var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( loadModel );

                manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                    console.log( item, loaded, total );

                };

                // texture

                var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

                var texture = textureLoader.load( 'textures/hardwood2_diffuse.jpg' );

                // model

                function onProgress( xhr ) {

                    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

                        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                        console.log( 'model ' + Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

                    }

                }

                function onError() {}

                var loader = new OBJLoader( manager );

                loader.load( 'models/obj/goku/' + name, function ( obj ) {

                    object = obj;
object.position.x = 0;
object.position.z = 1;
object.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);


                }, onProgress, onError );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );


                // controls

                controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

                //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)

                controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
                controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

                // controls.screenSpacePanning = true;

                // controls.minDistance = 100;
                // controls.maxDistance = 500;

                // controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }



            // function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
            //
            //  mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            //  mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;
            //
            // }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                // camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                // camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

                // camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
controls.update(); // only required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with modules, you can't refer to module scope functions like so:

```
<a onclick="changename('GameBoy');">click</a>
```

That does not work since `changename()` only exists in module but not in global scope. You have to add the click event listener by defining an `id` for your link/button and then select it like so:

```
const element = document.getElementById( 'myButton' );
element.addEventListener( 'click', changename );
```

Notice that you can't pass the `newname` parameter like in your original code. Consider to store it in a [data attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) if you want to reuse the function.

Even if you register the event listener like that, your code will not work as intended. Simply because `changename()` only changes the name but does not trigger a new call of `OBJLoader.load()`.

Comment: Thank you! Got it, i think, i did what you suggested and the good thing is that i got no error and got an alert to trigger, now this is where im dumb, i had to read the last sentence like 10 times, until i kinda got it, so my dumb self, copied pasted the whole //Manager section on the function AND IT TRIGGERED A 2ND MODEL now i have 2 models at the same time LOL. but with different name AHA! now im going to figure out how to disposes of the old model and im getting the feeling i missed the point of something you mentioned... i did create a data attribute just in case.

Comment: Great! Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.